# deploying machine learning models in django

Tags: django, xgboost

I have a model that I want to use for predictions which I have loaded using pickle and I have a form created in using django. But when a user submits the form I want it to be in store it in a csv format in a variable so I can perform Xgboost prediction on every form the user fills and after it outputs the prediction. COuld it be its not getting any input. New to this

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
# Create your models here.
type_loan=(("Cash loan","Cash loan"),
            ("Revolving loan","Revolving Loan"))
Gender=(("Male","Male"),
        ("Female","Female"))
Yes_NO=(("YES","YES"),("NO","NO"))
status=(("Single","Single"),
        ("Married","Married"),
        ("Widow","Widow"),
        ("Seprated","Divorce"))
Highest_Education=(("Secondary","Secondary"),
                    ("Incomplete Higher","Incomplete Higher"),
                    ("Lower Secondary","Lower Secondary"),
                    ("Academic Degree","Academic Degree"))
Income_type=(("Working","Working Class"),
            ("State Servant","Civil Servant"),
            ("Commercial Associate","Commercial Associate"),
            ("Pensioner","Pensioner"),
            ("Student","Student"),
            ("Businessman","Business Owner"))


class Applicant(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(default="Jon Samuel",max_length=50,null="True")
    Birth_date=models.DateField(default="2018-03-12",blank=False, null=True)
    Status=models.CharField(choices=status,max_length=50)
    Children=models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(17)])
    Highest_Education=models.CharField(choices=Highest_Education,max_length=50)
    Gender=models.CharField(choices=Gender, max_length=50)
    loan_type=models.CharField(choices=type_loan, max_length=50)
    own_a_car=models.CharField(choices=Yes_NO,max_length=50)
    own_a_house=models.CharField(choices=Yes_NO,max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Applicant
from .forms import Applicant_form
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from django.core.cache import cache
import xgboost as xgb
import pickle
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

class CreateMyModelView(CreateView):
    model = Applicant
    form_class = Applicant_form
    template_name = 'loan/index.html'
    success_url = '/loan/results'
    context_object_name = 'name'

class MyModelListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'loan/result.html'
    context_object_name = 'Results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset=Applicant.objects.all()
        with open('model/newloan_model','rb') as f:
            clf=pickle.load(f)
        le=LabelEncoder()
        le.fit(queryset)
        queryset=le.transform(queryset)
        d_test = xgb.DMatrix(queryset) 
        predict=clf.predict(d_test)
        return (predict)
```

TRaceback

```
File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "/home/david/loan60/loan/views.py", line 27, in get_queryset
    data=le.fit_transform(queryset)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 235, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 797, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (3, 10)
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:28] "GET /loan/results HTTP/1.1" 500 92945
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2078
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6230
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 200 17976
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 81348
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 80304
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 82564
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-changelink.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-addlink.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:35] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-deletelink.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /admin/loan/applicant/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4808
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/css/changelists.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/js/core.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/js/urlify.js HTTP/1.1" 200 8972
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/js/prepopulate.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/js/actions.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.js HTTP/1.1" 200 128820
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 271751
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:38] "GET /static/admin/img/tooltag-add.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:48] "POST /admin/loan/applicant/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3636
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:48] "GET /static/admin/js/cancel.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:50] "POST /admin/loan/applicant/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:50] "GET /admin/loan/applicant/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3310
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:50] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:50] "GET /static/admin/img/icon-yes.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Internal Server Error: /loan/results
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "/home/david/loan60/loan/views.py", line 28, in get_queryset
    d_test = xgb.DMatrix(data) #changing the data to matrix form
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 382, in __init__
    self._init_from_npy2d(data, missing, nthread)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 450, in _init_from_npy2d
    raise ValueError('Input numpy.ndarray must be 2 dimensional')
ValueError: Input numpy.ndarray must be 2 dimensional
[11/Dec/2018 18:46:57] "GET /loan/results HTTP/1.1" 500 93391
[11/Dec/2018 18:47:04] "GET /loan/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2494
[11/Dec/2018 18:47:09] "POST /loan/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Internal Server Error: /loan/results
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "/home/david/loan60/loan/views.py", line 27, in get_queryset
    data=le.fit_transform(queryset)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 235, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 797, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (1, 10)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the *full* traceback. At first sight it looks like you somewhere want to *order* your objects, but by default Django objects have no order.

Comment: What I intend to do is actually collect what the present user has filled in the form and run the input through the model I created using xgboost and output the prediction.

Comment: There is a tutorial how to deploy machine learning models with Django: https://deploymachinelearning.com with code available at github: https://github.com/pplonski/my_ml_service

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic import View,TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages,auth
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import os
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Prediction
from django.contrib import messages



def dashboard(request):

        if request.method=='POST':

                report = request.POST['report']
                patient_id = request.POST['patient_id']
                if len(patient_id)!=6:
                        messages.error(request, 'patient id invalid')
                        return redirect('dashboard')
                elif report == '':
                        messages.error(request, 'Report is empty')
                        return redirect('dashboard')

                elif patient_id == '':
                        messages.error(request, 'Patient id is empty')
                        return redirect('dashboard')



                else:

                        model=joblib.load('naccounts/piped.pkl')
                        predictions=model.predict([report])
                        #print (prediction)
                        messages.success(request, (predictions[0]))

                        prediction=Prediction(patient_id=patient_id,report=report,predictions=predictions[0])
                        prediction.save()
                        return render(request, 'naccounts/dashboard.html')


        else:

                return render(request,'naccounts/dashboard.html')




def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,'You are now logged in')
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        return render(request,'index')







def logout(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       auth.logout(request)
       return redirect('index')

You can check that code.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.